# NullPointerException in dao.save method

Tags: java, hibernate, dao

I'm learning Spring framework and using DAO. When I use my dao.save method to persist new object to database I got NullPointerException. How can i solve this problem and correctly persist/delete/update objects to databases ? Thanks.

Entity **Coffee.class** :

```
@Entity
public class Coffee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String coffeeName;

    private Integer costForCup;

    private boolean isDisabled;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "coffee")
    private Set<Coffee> coffee;

    public Coffee() {}

    public Coffee(String coffeeName, Integer costForCup, boolean isDisabled) {
        this.coffeeName = coffeeName;
        this.costForCup = costForCup;
        this.isDisabled = isDisabled;
    }
*getters and setters*
```

CoffeeDAO :

```
public interface CoffeeDAO {

    public Coffee findById(Long id);

    public List<Coffee> findAll();

    public void createCoffee(Coffee coffee);

}
```

**CoffeeDAOImpl** :

```
public class CoffeeImplementation implements CoffeeDAO {

private HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate;

public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory){
    this.hibernateTemplate = new HibernateTemplate(sessionFactory);
}

***
@Override
@Transactional
public void createCoffee(Coffee coffee) {
    hibernateTemplate.save(coffee);
}

}
```

**OrderBean.class** :

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class OrderBean {



     @Autowired
        private CoffeeDAO coffeeDAO; 
public boolean createCoffee(){
            Coffee coffee = new Coffee("Кофе", 4, true);
            System.out.println(coffee.getCoffeeName()+" " + coffee.getCostForCup() + " " + coffee.isDisabled());
            coffeeDAO.createCoffee(coffee);
            return true;
    }
```

**Error logs**:

```
Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javacoff.beans.OrderBean.createCoffee(OrderBean.java:88)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.el.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:329)
    at org.jboss.el.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:342)
    at org.jboss.el.parser.AstPropertySuffix.invoke(AstPropertySuffix.java:58)
    at org.jboss.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:96)
    at org.jboss.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:276)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    ... 33 more
```

Comment: Based on the code you've posted, it appears that you expect an implementation of  the CoffeeDAO interface to get injected into `OrderBean`. Is it possible that you need to add an appropriate annotation like `@Repository` to `CoffeeImplementation`, liike this: `@Repository("coffeeDAO")`. This will allow your DI container (Spring?) to autowire the coffeeDAO.

Comment: I add this annotation like this `@Repository("coffeeDAO")
public class CoffeeImplementation implements CoffeeDAO`, but it doesnt help. Still the same NullPointerException error.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could add all of your code. However, one more thing to try: Add an annotation `@Qualifier("coffeeDAO")` just before or after your `@Autowired` annotation. This explicitly tells your container (Spring) the name of the bean to use to do the autowiring. Also, Spring must know the package containing your annotated beans (`OrderBean` and `CoffeeImplementation`), and allows Spring to load the beans into the DI container. see: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve my problem with `SpringBeanAutowiringSupport` in my managed bean:`public class OrderBean extends SpringBeanAutowiringSupport`.